# Need to find clusters and their centroids in a h5 crowd density map file

Tags: cluster-analysis, tracking, centroid

I'm trying to use clustering techniques which should allow me to find centroids (or medoids) for each group of people inside a density map (of a real photo). I could I reach that? I've already used Kmeans strategy, and maybe the calculated centroids could be also correct. But how could I better view them over the image?

h5 file: [density map of a crowd - points are representing people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o8wC.png)

Download the ".h5" from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5xvEQELswr4SJ5zhtYtUEVw2FbP2QWo/view?usp=sharing

I obtain the matrix of this h5 file through this code:

```
import sys
import numpy
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im

with h5py.File('/content/img001001.h5', 'r') as hf:
    h5_matrix= hf.get('density')[:]
plt.imshow(h5_matrix)
#print(h5_matrix[:, 1])
print(h5_matrix.shape)
```

Printed matrix look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f376lUPaWT58iBIg5E693uQfC22g5m3U/view?usp=sharing

what I would like to find and have: [density map with centroids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxwFX.png)
How could I afford that?